# JSF: datatable row manyselect

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, web, primefaces

i want to select many items from a list of Utilisateur(Users) but the checkbox is repeated for each line 
eg:i have 2 Users in Db and this is why it appears that two checkbox on the values ​​of a for each Users for each line of datatble

this is my xhtml file:

```
    <p:dataTable id="dta" value="#{UtilisateurComponent.listUtilisateurs()}"  var="current" rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
        <p:column>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox id="selectUser" value="#{ProjetComponent.projet.utilisateurs}"   >
                <f:selectItems value="#{UtilisateurComponent.listUtilisateurs()}" var="utilisateurs" itemValue="#{utilisateurs.iduser}" itemLabel=""/>
            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
        </p:column>
        <p:column> 
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{utilisateurmsgs['utilisateur.datederniereconnexion.title']}" />
            </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{current.datederniereconnexion}" converter="dateTimeConverterForCalendar" />
        </p:column>
```

and this the generated form[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because you did this:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{UtilisateurComponent.listUtilisateurs()}" var="utilisateurs" itemValue="#{utilisateurs.iduser}" itemLabel=""/>
```

f:selectItems - It get the data from a list and create the checkboxes by the list size.

You need to do something like this, Use the var in the p:dataTable.

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{utilisateurs.iduser}" itemLabel="blabla"/>
```

Notice also that i have changed selectItems to selectItem.

Look at this link.. You have exactly the example you want in the bottom.. Table with check boxes
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml